Non-MCU Driver IC for 24 bit parallel RGB display?
I'm working on a project that requires a 24 bit parallel RGB display. I originally planned to drive it with an STMH7B3 MCU using the built-in LTDC interface. The problem is the LTDC interface uses a lot of pins (28) and the pin assignments conflict with the USB and DCMI interfaces, which I may need to use. I know there are larger packages in the STMH7B3 family that would work without conflict. But I prefer to use a smaller package since I don't need that many GPIOs outside of the LTDC, USB and DCMI interfaces.
I was wondering if there exists any specialized ICs (not an MCU) that can drive the 24 bit display? I'm envisioning a chip that receives display data over SPI (or other common protocols) and outputs the RGB signals directly to the display.
Does such a chip exist? In all my research, I've only across other microcontrollers that can do this.
Does anyone have experience with directly driving a 24 bit RGB display? Are there better ways to do this than what I've described?

An IO expander perhaps? Maybe use something other than the built-in USB controller, like an FT232? If you don't have to use all three interfaces at once, multiplex them? If all else fails, you could almost certainly do it with a cheap FPGA.

Good thought on using an external USB to UART chip to avoid the conflict. I might just do that. We're basically locked in on using this STM family at this stage.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

You're asking about an LCD video display controller. There are  some out there, but you'd have to ask questions about how long they'll be around since that stuff tends to move on-chip as quickly as possible and they tend to be aimed at consumer-ish applications that are pretty fickle.
One thing you could consider is using two MCUs that are identical or from the same family. Since you already have invested in the toolchain, it could work out without adding too much overhead.
Last time I looked at this, the frame buffer was pretty constraining, depending on the display size and resolution. It's a lot of RAM for a chip and external RAM tends to be a bit expensive and the suppliers, again, a bit fickle. For example, the S70KL1281DABHI023.

Thanks for the answer. This sort of confirms to me that using an MCU is the most straightforward way to accomplish this. Supply chain issues scare me. I'll probably try to get around the interface conflict by using the idea from hearth's comment. One of the reasons I chose the STM32H7B3ZI is because it has plenty of RAM to store 2-3 buffer frames.
